# Algorithm for high contrast

Tags: algorithms, image-processing

Using [this](http://www.dfstudios.co.uk/articles/programming/image-programming-algorithms/image-processing-algorithms-part-5-contrast-adjustment/) algorithm I can increase contrast but applications like Paint.Net can increase contrast significantly. For example it can convert
[image: this image] to [image: this image] (by setting contrast to 100 and brightness to 100, whatever it means).
So my question is if there is any particular algorithm or this is something custom?

Comment: There exist many methods to do this. If I get to it, I can show you one. It's a bit computationally demanding and theoretical, but get really cool results.

Comment: i appreciate that. Is there any common name for these algorithms?